# Installing libzippp library with cmake not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, libzip

Trying to install [libzippp](https://github.com/ctabin/libzippp) library in [this project](https://github.com/AlejandroCamba/screenshot-to-text-generator)  is not working for some reason, here is my project's CMakeLists.txt:

> 

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(startProject)
set(Leptonica_DIR /Users/alejandrocamba/Documents/leptonica/build)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(Leptonica REQUIRED)
find_package(Tesseract REQUIRED)
find_package(libzippp 3.0 REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${Leptonica_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${Tesseract_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(startProject main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(startProject libzipp::libzipp)
target_link_libraries(startProject ${OpenCV_LIBS})
target_link_libraries(startProject ${Tesseract_LIBRARIES})
```

I'm getting the error:

```
ld: library not found for -llibzipp::libzipp
```

I have followed the instructions and i cloned the repository and successfully installed it, so if i do `make install` i get:

[image]

But i can't seem to find a way to use it on my project, i need help to make get it working on my project!

Comment: See the example CMake [file](https://github.com/ctabin/libzippp/blob/5106b5104fc72fb771d378b436e872c861cc9f3c/tests/exampleProject/CMakeLists.txt) in the repo. You need 3 p's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need more `p`: the proper target name for link with is `libzippp::libzippp`.

The [project's README](https://github.com/ctabin/libzippp/blob/master/README.md) wrongly suggests to use `libzipp::libzipp`.